# Appending to a list of lists in Python, with conditions

Tags: python, list, iteration

I am iterating over such objects and creating a list of lists.

Something like this:

```
#data.py
values = []
for o in objects:
    data = [o.day, o.seconds]
    values.append(data)
```

So that gives me, for example:

```
[['27/2', 34], ['23/2', 21], ['25/2', 11], ['27/2', 38]]
```

But I need to make an additional operation. If `data[0] (day)` is already in values, I don't want to append data, I want to add `data[1]` to the existing object's `data[1]`.

So from the above list, what I really want is:

```
[['27/2', 72], ['23/2', 21], ['25/2', 11]]
```

I can do the operation without a list, but, at the end, I need to convert it to a list for final use.

Comment: You should also provide your example input and use a different variable name because `object` is a built-in in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to use a `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
values = defaultdict(int)
for o in my_object:
    values[o.day] += o.seconds
```

Here's a way using a `Counter`

```
from itertools import Counter
values = Counter()
for o in my_object:
    values += Counter({o.day: o.seconds})
```

You can get a list from values like this

```
values.items() # or list(values.items()) in Python3
```

Comment: Many good answers, but I went with the first one here, using defaultdict. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I would use a dictionary if I were you.

```
values = {}
for item in object_: # changed object to object_
    values[item.day] = values.get(item.day, 0) + item.seconds
```

Comment: Changed `data` to `values`, which is I think what you meant. Let me know if it wasn't. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice one-liner (barring imports) that should do what you need:

```
from collections import Counter
values = sum([Counter({o.day: o.seconds}) for o in objects], Counter()).items()
```